# Crash Report iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have made distribution build for my customer and after customer tested it he got this crash reporter below, but I don't understand this exception log, because here are not any issue with my methods and the last string says about CoreFoundation issue. How can I track this issue. Maybe will be better get from customer step to reproduce instead of crash log or may be I don't see something important in this log.

```
Incident Identifier: F63F6B5A-11B0-4F82-A9B9-40244904B66A
CrashReporter Key:   12c58ee8ba26d7ae1b333ac625b598ca1bb141bd
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         EducationApp [1253]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F3C257A7-763D-4B12-A7FF-E251501B3785/EducationApp.app/EducationApp
Identifier:      EducationApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-04-29 23:51:21.645 -0400
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3359f29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b21d97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3359f1c0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   QuartzCore                      0x35153976 CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) + 206
4   QuartzCore                      0x3515389e -[CALayer setPosition:] + 46
5   QuartzCore                      0x3515382e -[CALayer setFrame:] + 534
6   UIKit                           0x353a8ae8 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 228
7   UIKit                           0x353a8810 -[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] + 180
8   UIKit                           0x353a874e -[UIImageView setFrame:] + 34
9   EducationApp                    0x0008d532 0x8b000 + 9522
10  EducationApp                    0x0009964c 0x8b000 + 58956
11  EducationApp                    0x00099192 0x8b000 + 57746
12  EducationApp                    0x000a0340 0x8b000 + 86848
13  UIKit                           0x353c6590 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
14  UIKit                           0x3540ffd2 -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 54
15  UIKit                           0x3540ff40 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 92
16  UIKit                           0x354944ea -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 3594
17  UIKit                           0x35492fe2 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3390
18  UIKit                           0x355b53ea -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
19  EducationApp                    0x00090c0e 0x8b000 + 23566
20  EducationApp                    0x0008ffa0 0x8b000 + 20384
21  UIKit                           0x3540e30c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132
22  UIKit                           0x35448d10 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 236
23  UIKit                           0x354bdd14 -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1432
24  UIKit                           0x354426ba -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 294
25  UIKit                           0x35442494 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 912
26  UIKit                           0x35441dde -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 2242
27  UIKit                           0x35682614 __91-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]_block_invoke_0238 + 384
28  UIKit                           0x354949b4 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 4820
29  UIKit                           0x35504810 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1704
30  UIKit                           0x354507c0 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 908
31  EducationApp                    0x0009994a 0x8b000 + 59722
32  EducationApp                    0x000993d6 0x8b000 + 58326
33  UIKit                           0x354920c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
34  UIKit                           0x35492072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
35  UIKit                           0x35492050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
36  UIKit                           0x35491906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
37  UIKit                           0x35491dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
38  UIKit                           0x353ba5ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
39  UIKit                           0x353a77fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
40  UIKit                           0x353a7116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
41  GraphicsServices                0x3709959e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
42  GraphicsServices                0x370991ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
43  CoreFoundation                  0x3357416e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
44  CoreFoundation                  0x33574112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
45  CoreFoundation                  0x33572f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
46  CoreFoundation                  0x334e5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
47  CoreFoundation                  0x334e5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
48  GraphicsServices                0x370982e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
49  UIKit                           0x353fb2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
50  EducationApp                    0x0008ca5e 0x8b000 + 6750
51  EducationApp                    0x0008c9ec 0x8b000 + 6636


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b71b350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b69211e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b6ce96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac6cd4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac69ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b21da74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac6a078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac6a110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac6b594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b21d9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x334e5f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x334e5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x370982e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x353fb2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  EducationApp                    0x0008ca5e 0x8b000 + 6750
15  EducationApp                    0x0008c9ec 0x8b000 + 6636

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b70b648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b6444ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b636df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b70aeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b70b048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33574040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33572d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x334e5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x334e5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x394d3500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b67430e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b6741d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b71bd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b669cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b669a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b6698a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3d1cc534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3d1ccb88      r6: 0x1cd92884      r7: 0x2fd75a24
    r8: 0x1cd92860    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0421cdc0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd75a18      lr: 0x3b692123      pc: 0x3b71b350
  cpsr: 0x00080010

Binary Images:
   0x8b000 -    0xa9fff +EducationApp armv7  <7346586e927b3d288b9bb5978c992ed3> /var/mobile/Applications/F3C257A7-763D-4B12-A7FF-E251501B3785/EducationApp.app/EducationApp
0x2feb2000 - 0x2fed2fff  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x327a7000 - 0x327a7fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x327a8000 - 0x328e6fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x328e7000 - 0x329cafff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x329cb000 - 0x32c80fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32c81000 - 0x32cdafff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32cdb000 - 0x32cecfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x32ced000 - 0x32cedfff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32cee000 - 0x32cfffff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x32d01000 - 0x32d65fff  AddressBook armv7  <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x331f4000 - 0x332b9fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x332ba000 - 0x33310fff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33324000 - 0x334dcfff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x334dd000 - 0x3360ffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33610000 - 0x33748fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3374a000 - 0x33785fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33969000 - 0x33984fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33985000 - 0x33a3afff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33ac8000 - 0x33b2dfff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33bb7000 - 0x33c0dfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33c0e000 - 0x33c70fff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33c71000 - 0x33c80fff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33e05000 - 0x33fc8fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34183000 - 0x341ccfff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x341cd000 - 0x343a5fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x348bc000 - 0x34915fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34a04000 - 0x34a0bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34a0d000 - 0x34a0dfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x34a11000 - 0x34a13fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x34a14000 - 0x34a18fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34a19000 - 0x34a56fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35151000 - 0x35266fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x352b5000 - 0x352e3fff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35362000 - 0x353a1fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x353a4000 - 0x358f8fff  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x358f9000 - 0x35937fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35bbc000 - 0x35bc8fff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35c14000 - 0x35c17fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36043000 - 0x3607efff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x360f1000 - 0x360fafff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36115000 - 0x3612cfff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x36136000 - 0x3615afff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36363000 - 0x3637cfff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <ec2f76b3ac723a39bbf3f122d7fe73cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x36390000 - 0x36395fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x3665b000 - 0x3665cfff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x366c9000 - 0x366cefff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x368a0000 - 0x368b2fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x368f1000 - 0x368f2fff  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x368f5000 - 0x3690efff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36981000 - 0x36d94fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x36f8c000 - 0x36f98fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x37093000 - 0x3709efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3738a000 - 0x373d6fff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x373dd000 - 0x373defff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x373df000 - 0x373e4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x373e5000 - 0x373e9fff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x37433000 - 0x375d9fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x375ff000 - 0x37609fff  Librarian armv7  <2f90575c8cf839da9db74d2eb3a1ccc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x376a5000 - 0x376fdfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x378d4000 - 0x37901fff  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x37946000 - 0x37949fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3794a000 - 0x37950fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x379ad000 - 0x379b0fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x37b61000 - 0x37b63fff  OAuth armv7  <575df12a2f2436af92e31494c3b74465> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x3829d000 - 0x382c2fff  OpenCL armv7  <9baf655cae4e3f9f99a5c6a99207099d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x38623000 - 0x38640fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <c773b3dc885832f8a916de67f24f9f92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x388d6000 - 0x388fefff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x388ff000 - 0x38973fff  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x38ab8000 - 0x38ac9fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <0e48e91ad40f34aab3323c7c4157ce52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x38c54000 - 0x38c56fff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x38c75000 - 0x38c82fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x38c83000 - 0x390a7fff  TextInput armv7  <d54d5ca42b503f26ab45e5efd4b87135> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x39105000 - 0x391a5fff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x391a6000 - 0x391befff  Ubiquity armv7  <d72afdd00be23174984d033f197059f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Ubiquity
0x394a9000 - 0x394c8fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x394c9000 - 0x39df8fff  WebCore armv7  <06c849df1ad435aeb8b6130d85cee5df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x39df9000 - 0x39ed6fff  WebKit armv7  <e0768dbdbdf13c769af7959497e24024> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x39f81000 - 0x39f88fff  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3aa96000 - 0x3aa9cfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3aa9d000 - 0x3aab3fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3aacb000 - 0x3aad7fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <d0dce72a604b37309b8714fb35d74468> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3aae9000 - 0x3aae9fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3ac07000 - 0x3ac13fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3ac14000 - 0x3ac1dfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3ac1e000 - 0x3ac68fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3ac69000 - 0x3ac7cfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3aca8000 - 0x3aca8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e7e2e533904235d7869baf2ef943407e> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3acad000 - 0x3ad9afff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3ad9b000 - 0x3aee4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3aeec000 - 0x3aeecfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3aeef000 - 0x3aef6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <224c65d491603e21a78a00af9e10f012> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3b033000 - 0x3b1d6fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <0747e596e9983bd6a76cf8349da325e4> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3b1d7000 - 0x3b1ecfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <7502589f14733beb963c542fa40438c8> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3b215000 - 0x3b313fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3b3d7000 - 0x3b3ecfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3b411000 - 0x3b496fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cbefd01867b93d2a869a534825a1414c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3b497000 - 0x3b4e2fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e3154b06ac5d360c948111abfb2bc339> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3b4e3000 - 0x3b509fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c43990ee3a5e389aacf288c3615a50dc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3b50d000 - 0x3b5bafff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3b5bb000 - 0x3b5dbfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <d327d9e0f43333568abda8d83558c8a9> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3b5dc000 - 0x3b5e8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <3ea49513bc023326be68e35324c11d0e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3b5e9000 - 0x3b5ecfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <91862e82d5063531b4fb4da9a19e5365> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3b5ed000 - 0x3b5f3fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <d9e66574881739e8b25c3ae087a9f409> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3b5f4000 - 0x3b5f6fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <6ac449c92d743640a23d9d1ebe0b48a9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3b5f7000 - 0x3b5fcfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <87bcae8743ab35c8a070ac95b7d57acb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3b5fd000 - 0x3b632fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <04b464137fc2304b84eeed1a5418f4a8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3b633000 - 0x3b650fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9323bb560d4e3a3fb41efdc78bd0cf94> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3b651000 - 0x3b652fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <c25502085c833181b2a12cf525cffde6> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3b653000 - 0x3b654fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f0b2fad1b720361297e22866c5c0fb64> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3b655000 - 0x3b655fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <e19c865e73e2352bbc8022033e953f22> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3b656000 - 0x3b65bfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <c8bedc36bc3d3b55b91b12ebb1240968> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3b65c000 - 0x3b65ffff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <965ab939e24935e7a3a65981574a7745> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3b660000 - 0x3b661fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <295706037a5238b4aa145df7b9354a0e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3b662000 - 0x3b662fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <50a01a02f573317fbd21e1070b0afc7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3b663000 - 0x3b6e9fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <cacc68d271e53338b7780c26f651b767> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3b6ea000 - 0x3b6f0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3b6f1000 - 0x3b709fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3b70a000 - 0x3b720fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7d409890411a396a9c812f488f8ea99a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3b721000 - 0x3b73dfff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3b73e000 - 0x3b74cfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <afc167a2e9be3dd6851da8deaf42bafd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3b74d000 - 0x3b754fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <c1d71aa978383c51a9ba2b32782d6cc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3b755000 - 0x3b756fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3b757000 - 0x3b757fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <df8f1d90cbb837cc92d5901fab94e6ca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3b758000 - 0x3b76dfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: You can use some crash report service, for example http://crashlytics.com/ .

Comment: You need the dSYM file so you can symbolicate the crash report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your project. GoTo Edit Scheme > In the left side bar Select Run "YourApp.app" > Now select Diagnostics Tab > Under Memory Management - Enable Zombie Objects.

When you run you app and it crashes during Zombie mode, you will get the proper error message and the exact place where the program crashed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a view is null. It could be a zombie (if you are not using ARC) or you are loading a NIB file that doesn't exist in the project or you have some property (likely a view) that has never been set or was cleared and then positioned.

I too would suggest you integrate something like crashlytics (which we use and like a lot), this allows instant crash reporting to you and they auto symbolize the report for you.